# Does anyone know if Google plans to release an Earth API on Android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-earth

Now that Google Earth has been released for Android 2.1, does anyone know what, if any, plans there are to extend the Google API's to support it in a future version?

Comment: Also, is there a better forum to post this type of question?  None of the others in the FAQ seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "Google APIs"?

If you mean the Android SDK, there are very few APIs related to their apps, so I wouldn't hold my breath.

If you mean Web-based Google Earth APIs somehow becoming Android-aware or something, I don't know much about that, or even if such things exist.

Comment: I'm referring to the the Android Google API, which currently supports MapViews: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html